# Rails: Cucumber tests (with JS) failing after adding assets to CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, asset-pipeline, poltergeist

I'm pretty new to rails so this is a bit of mystery to me.

I've added some font files to `app/assets/fonts` and included them in a SCSS file using `asset-url` helper. However I'm now getting errors similar to:

`No route matches assets/9df317a3-a79e-422e-b4e2-35ccd29cd5b7 (ActionController::RoutingError)`

(note the missing file extension?)

on my Cucumber tests, but **only** on tests with the `@javascript` flag. I've tried the following:

`RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:precompile`

and the fixes in this thread didn't work:

[Capybara tests with :js=>true... Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/assets"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629491/capybara-tests-with-js-true-routing-error-no-route-matches-get-assets)

The thread suggests that there is an incorrect asset somewhere, but this happens even if I remove all but one file from my CSS. Plus the app reports no 404s and the fonts are working in the dev env. **These are the only assets in the app!**

I'm using:

- Rails 4
- Cucumber
- Capybara
- Poltergeist (for JS tests)

Css:

```
@font-face{
  font-family:"l baskerville w01_n4";
  src:asset-url("8dc59876-75a4-4e80-bd1a-735d5f043beb.eot?#iefix")format("eot")
}
etc...
```

(the files are provided by fonts.com [hence the horrible filenames])

environments/test.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_files   = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Randomize the order test cases are executed.
  config.active_support.test_order = :random

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm guessing this is an issue with the asset pipeline in a test and production environment. But I don't know where to start.

Thanks,

LM

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is a simple syntax error:

`src: asset-url("8dc59876-75a4-4e80-bd1a-735d5f043beb.eot?#iefix")format("eot")`

Should be:

`src: font-url(url("8dc59876-75a4-4e80-bd1a-735d5f043beb.eot?#iefix")) format("eot")`

Hopefully this is useful to some other newbies like me.