# Capybara with :js => true causes routing errors for fontawesome fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, font-awesome

I'm getting the following error when I run Capybara tests with js: true option:

```
No route matches [GET] "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff"
```

Obviously, this error is not related to the Capybara but to the Font Awesome.

I found a solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945023/513554, 
but after some investigation I found another workaround which may help people.

So I post a Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

Make following modifications in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  get 'fonts/*anything' => 'fonts#dummy'
end
```

And create a separate controller:

```
class FontsController < ApplicationController
  def dummy
    head :ok
  end
end
```

By setting `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true`, your tests get passed but routing error messages are scattered around your `test.log`. My workaround doesn't have such a downside.