# Capybara: Stubbing No Route Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, capybara

I have a capybara test that checks for content on a page. I have an img tag thats src calls for a URL that does not exist. When I run the test I receive:

```
Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

  ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches [GET] "/avatars/original/missing.png"
```

I honestly don't care about this request. Is there any way for me stub `/avatars/original/missing.png` on my Capybara test?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629491/capybara-tests-with-js-true-routing-error-no-route-matches-get-assets

Comment: @Hitham Although somewhat helpful, I couldn't find a direct answer to my question. In all of those cases, they were trying to fix their asset pipeline. I don't care about that. I just want to stub it out.

Comment: Fix your asset pipeline so you don't have to stub out something that you shouldn't have to stub.

Comment: @ruby_newbie, Let me further explain. There is nothing wrong with my asset pipeline. My pipeline works perfectly. The problem is is that the img src is being retrieved from a database record which I have no control in changing. So either I create a route for this image or stub it. I would prefer to stub it.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: @TomWalpole, poltergeist.

Comment: You can use the blacklist functionality in poltergeist to block those url requests. If using 1.10+ you can do it in the driver config - otherwise per test in a before block

Comment: @TomWalpole, this is a great direction. So far I'm determining how to set it so it blacklists relative url links. My url is pointing to within the app itself.

Comment: @TomWalpole, got it to work. Ended up using a before block in the test itself. Post as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Poltergeist you can use the blacklist functionality to block specific requests.  If using Poltergeist 1.10.0+ you can configure it for every test in the driver registration block by adding the :url_blacklist option

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  #  Change domain name as necessary
  options = { url_blacklist: ['http://www.example.com/avatars/original/missing.png'] } # you can also use * as a wildcard
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

In pre 1.10 or if you want to do it on a test by test/before block basis you can do

```
page.driver.browser.url_blacklist = ['http://www.example.com/avatars/original/missing.png']
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I blacklist to black a request when using Capybara.default_driver = :selenium